# mobile query takes over the desktop view

Tags: css, media-queries

**This code written on top my stylesheet should change my text color to red in a desktop view**

```
.info-paragraph{
   color: red;
}
```

**Media query for the same code on mobile phones display**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .info-paragraph{
      color: white;
      font-size: 2.855rem;
      line-height: 3rem;
      font-family: 'Mallanna', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
```

**Result:**
My code works perfectly with the set media query for mobile phones, but its quite strange why `color:red` will not work in desktop view. What am I doing wrong guys?

Answer (score 3):

You should try using **max-width instead of min-width**, everything inside that media query should run fine!

Comment: Thanks alot @adam Torok, it worked when I set media to max-width, can you explain to me while the previous min-width did not work?

Comment: On screens that are 786px or less, max-width is media query is triggered, your min query would only trigger, if the screen is more then 786px thus, thats not mobile :)

Comment: Wow! that's simple English, always getting me confused. Thanks ones again for clearing the confusion.